# custom color in vscode tree view node

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I want to update tree view item color in my vscode extension. This is similar to how vscode's explorer pane has green color for a newly created file, and red for a deleted file. I can only find customization for icon but not for text in treeview API.

[image: vscode tree view node]

Comment: VSC core has more possibilities then extension API in the tree view, if you want full control use a WebviewView

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want a Webview. I already have a tree view with so and so functionalities, can't just change to webview for one feature.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74486107/how-to-color-tree-view-item-in-vscode-extension/74493474?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C30.3913#74493474 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74449432/how-to-add-and-select-color-for-nodes-tree-view-items-in-explorer-view-in-my-vsc/74483366?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C23.2860#74483366.