# how to color tree view item in VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have implemented my own explorer view for my extension by implementing vscode.TreeDataProvider<> Now I want to customize color of tree view item/node which is my root node (or it can be other specific node as well). To color tree view item , I have tried to implement vscode.FileDecorationProvider interface and register this to vscode.window.registerFileDecorationProvider(); But I am not able to provide custom color for tree view item. Is there any sample code for this ? or any pointer to achieve this?

Comment: Custom colors are currently not possible.

Comment: you have to write your own explorer view tree in a WebviewView, then you have **full** control, most likely there is a HTML/JavaScript framework that has a tree widget

Comment: See also your answered question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74449432/how-to-add-and-select-color-for-nodes-tree-view-items-in-explorer-view-in-my-vsc/74483366#74483366 about using a FileDecorationProvider to apply themeColors to TreeItem labels.

Comment: @MikeLischke An extension can define its own theme colors which can then be used in a FileDecorationProvider.

Comment: To me this question sounds like it asks for general treeviews, not just for the file tree.

Comment: FileDecoration providers also decorate treeViews.

Answer (score 0):

- Readers of this answer should also refer to [how to add and select color for nodes/tree view items in explorer view in my vscode extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74449432/how-to-add-and-select-color-for-nodes-tree-view-items-in-explorer-view-in-my-vsc/74483366#74483366)

From [themeable colors in extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_16#_themable-colors-in-extensions), you can add a `colors` section to your `package.json`:

```
"contributes": {

    "colors": [
        {
            "id": "editorManager.treeItemTextForeground",
            "description": "Color for a TreeIteem label",
            "defaults": {
                "dark": "#00ccff",   // your own defined colors
                "light": "#00ccff",
                "highContrast": "errorForeground"  // you can also use existing color theme references here
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can create as many colors aas you need.  The `id` is just a name you can make up.  It can then be used in your FileDecorationProvider like so:

```js
  async provideFileDecoration(uri: Uri): Promise<FileDecoration | undefined> {
    const activeEditor = window.activeTextEditor.document.uri;
    if (uri.fsPath === activeEditor.fsPath) {
      return {
        badge: "⇐",
        // color: new ThemeColor("charts.red"), 
        color: new ThemeColor("editorManager.treeItemTextForeground"), // *****
        // color: new vscode.ThemeColor("tab.activeBackground"), 
        // tooltip: ""
      };
    }
    else return null;  // to get rid of the custom fileDecoration
  }
```

That color theme id will also be available to users of the extension to change in their `settings.json` `colorCustomizations` like so:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "editorManager.treeItemTextForeground": "#f00"
}
```

So you can create an initial default themeColor that can be applied to a `TreeItem` label via your `FileDecorationProvider`, but you don't know what color theme users might be using so they will and should have the ability to change your default colors if necessary in their own settings.

Comment: This is not working for treeview item instead it seems to be for the file open in the editor.

Comment: It does work to color TreeItem labels, I tested it.  you can use whatever you want to test against to change the color or nothing at all.